# Distributed Celery scheduler

Tags: python, celery

I'm looking for a distributed cron-like framework for Python, and found Celery. However, the docs says "You have to ensure only a single scheduler is running for a schedule at a time, otherwise you would end up with duplicate tasks", Celery is using celery.beat.PersistentScheduler which store the schedule to a local file.

So, my question, is there another implementation than the default that can put the schedule "into the cluster" and coordinate task execution so that each task is only run once?
My goal is to be able to run celerybeat with identical schedules on all hosts in the cluster.

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

**tl;dr**: No Celerybeat is not suitable for your use case. You have to run just one process of `celerybeat`, otherwise your tasks will be duplicated.

I know this is a very old question. I will try to make a small summary because I have the same problem/question (in the year 2018).

Some background: We're running Django application (with Celery) in the Kubernetes cluster. Cluster (EC2 instances) and Pods (~containers) are autoscaled: simply said, I do not know when and how many instances of the application are running.

It's your responsibility to run only one process of the `celerybeat`, otherwise, your tasks will be duplicated. **[1]** There was this feature request in the Celery repository: **[2]**

> Requiring the user to ensure that only one instance of celerybeat
>   exists across their cluster creates a substantial implementation
>   burden (either creating a single point-of-failure or encouraging users
>   to roll their own distributed mutex).
>
> celerybeat should either provide a mechanism to prevent inadvertent
>   concurrency, or the documentation should suggest a best-practice
>   approach.

After some time, this feature request was rejected by the author of Celery for lack of resources. **[3]** I highly recommend reading the entire thread on the Github. People there recommend these project/solutions:

- https://github.com/ybrs/single-beat
- https://github.com/sibson/redbeat
- Use locking mechanism (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time)

I did not try anything from the above (I do not want another dependency in my app and I do not like locking tasks /you need to deal with fail-over etc./).

I ended up using CronJob in Kubernetes (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

**[1]** [celerybeat - multiple instances & monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162338/celerybeat-multiple-instances-monitoring)

**[2]** https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/251

**[3]** https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/251#issuecomment-228214951

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some misunderstanding about what celerybeat does. Celerybeat does not process the periodic tasks; it only publishes them. It puts the periodic tasks on the queue to be processed by the celeryd workers. If you run a single celerybeat process and multiple celeryd processes then the task execution will be distributed into the cluster.

Comment: I understand that, what I want is to be able to run multiple celerybeat instances, so I can avoid the risk that if the host that runs celerybeat goes down the scheduling stops. I.e. a clustered scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue where we had three servers running Celerybeat.  However, our solution was to only run Celerybeat on a single server so duplicate tasks weren't created.  Why would you want Celerybeat running on multiple servers?

If you're worried about Celery going down just create a script to monitor that the Celerybeat process is still running.

```
$ ps aux | grep celerybeat
```

That will show you if the Celerybeat process is running.  Then create a script where if you see the process is down, email your system admins. [Here's a sample setup](http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2011/11/22/django-production-environment-setup-with-mongodb/) where we're only running Celerybeat on one server.

Comment: Not really an answer here. This is more like a workaround. The problem arises during deployment, suppose you need to distribute the app on several homogeneous nodes; taking care that only one node runs the scheduler means having a deployment procedure for all the nodes and another deployment procedure just for the "scheduler node"